# Is <EMBED> audio supported on iPad Safari?

Tags: ipad, html, safari, embed

Is the standard way to  audio on desktop browsers, supported on iPad Safari, like the one below;

http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2006/07/embed-mp3-files-into-your-website.html

I mean what are the ways to have embedded audio work on iPad Safari. I know HTML5  element can be used on iPad Safari..But are there any other ways to embed audio in iPad Safari?

Comment: I assume it supports Quicktime, but don't quote me on that. Just seems like an Apple product should support another Apple product.

Comment: I mean does it support <embed> the same that is used for desktop browsers...like will the same code work on iPad Safari ?

Comment: Also what plugin do we need in the desktop browser when we just include an embed MP3 code on our page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use the HTML5 audio tag if you're playing mp3's as it's future proofed and the support is rapidly growing. That'll cover all your iDevice requirements and most other mobile platforms and the latest / future deskstop browsers. I'd then use Flash as the fall back for older desktop browsers as nearly everyone has it installed and it works well.

HTML5Rocks gives a good example of how to do this: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/quick/